# How to do this update in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a few records as follows (USER_1, USER_2, USER_3, USER_4, USER_5, USER_6 are columns)

```
USER_1  USER_2  USER_3  USER_4  USER_5   USER_6
ABC01  12-Sept    A     100    12345         
ABC02  12-Sept    A     200    12346   
ABC03  12-Sept    A     300    12347   
ABC09  12-Sept    A     250    12369    Record not present on side B
ABC01  12-Sept    B     100    12345   
ABC02  12-Sept    B     200    12346   
ABC03  12-Sept    B     300    12347       
ABC10  12-Sept    B     350    12222  Record not present on side A
```

Explanation

We distinguish the records based on `USER_3` if user_3 is 'A' then it is considered `Side A,` if `user_3` is `'B'` then it is considered side 'B'. Now  if you see `ABC01, ABC02, ABC03` are present in both sides A and B. But if you see `ABC09` it is present only in side A not side B. When such is the case i want `USER_6` to be updated with the string `'Record not present on side B'`. I'm not able to know how to write a loop which can do this . Please any help will be greatly appreciated . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a correlated subquery:

```
update table t
    set user_6 = (select (case when min(user_3) <> max(user_3) then NULL
                               when min(user_3) = 'A' then 'Record not present on side B'
                               else 'Record not present on side A'
                          end)
                  from table t2
                  where t2.user_1 = t.user_1
                 );
```

Comment: Hi Gordon,all the records are in the same table. I just want update only on the records where corresonding records on Side B(or Side A) are not available. So since USER_1=ABC09 is available only in Side A i wanted to update UsER_SIX with the string.

Comment: @user2647888 . . . I don't understand your comment.  This query appears to do what the question asks.